# Why is get_the_category() saying that I have two categories?

Tags: categories

My post has only one category. The following code:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
```

gives me this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 22
            [name] => Style Guide
            [slug] => style-guide
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 22
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
            [object_id] => 391
            [cat_ID] => 22
            [category_count] => 2
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Style Guide
            [category_nicename] => style-guide
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Why is it double up?

Comment: I only see one array element, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: [count] => 2, [category_count] => 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the

```
[category_count] => 2
```

when you say "saying that I have two categories"?

If so, you should understand that category_count is not the number of cateogries that this post has, but rather it is 'the number of uses of this category (also stored as 'count')' - see [get_the_category function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category). The fact that there is only one array element in the returned object indicates that there is only 1 category assigned to this post.

```
count($categories)
```

... will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: I like the way you think :D (though `category_count` is an object property, not an array element :P)

Comment: Ah, that makes is a bit more clear.Better naming wouldn't hurt, e.g. `usages`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

`$categories[$i]->count` and `$categories[$i]->category_count` are the number of posts in the category, not the number of categories there are. `count( $categories )` will give you the number of categories there are. Each array element represents a category.